# Embed asp.net with SQL Server reading data and changing textbox field

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

I am creating a sql project. I used a `SqlDatareader` and textbox, but when I run it I got an error

> InvalidOperationException

My code is this, thanks for your help.

```
    protected void DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
                string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand
                        ("USE [PRODUCTS] SELECT QUALITIES FROM dbo.COMPUTERS WHERE ID = 0", con);
                    SqlDataReader reader;
                    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    TextBox1.Text = reader["QUALITIES"].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Yeah, and where do you get the error? What is the context?

Comment: It is a runtime error, when i choose 0 index from dropdown list asp.net server error shows ups:                                           129:                        SqlDataReader reader;
130:                        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
//here is the error131:                        TextBox1.Text = reader["QUALITIES"].ToString();
 132:                    }
 133:                }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not accounting for the case where your data reader has no rows.

Try this:

```
while(reader.Read())
{
    TextBox1.Text = reader["QUALITIES"].ToString();
}
```

Also note that the "Qualities" field in your database could potentially be null. You will want to protect against this as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should do a couple of error-checking tasks to better understand what is causing the problem.  Use a try/catch to analyze the exception more closely.  Also add a Finally block to close the reader.  And check if the reader has rows:

```
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

try
{
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        reader.Read();

        if (!reader.IsDBNull(0))
            TextBox1.Text = reader.GetString(0);
     }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Do something
}
finally
{
    reader.Close();
}
```